# which is the apt java keyword to skip java serialization

Tags: java

In a process of leaning java serialization concept, i was puzzled at one point. In java serialization process, we use 2 keywords to prevent serialization, i.e.., transient and static. If i don't want to save an instance variable, which keyword should i use, both does exactly the same.

```
Class A implements Serializable{
  private static int x;
  private transient int y;
  private transient static int x;
}
```

In the above code all the three instance variables are not saved in a process of serialization. Which keyword is apt and recommended to prevent serialization. Why does two keywords have almost the same functionality. What is the recommended way of declaration to prevent serialization. Correct me if I'm wrong, I'm still learning.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `static` keyword transforms an instance variable into a static variable. A side-effect is that the field is not serialized anymore... because it's not a field anymore.

A static variable is a variable of the class. An instance variable is a variable of the object, or instance of the class. You can't blindly go from one to the other.

Read the [tutorial page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) about instance and static variables.

The `transient` keyword is the right keyword to use, of course.

Answer (score 4):

You are confused: `static` fields *are not instance variables*, they are class-wide variables. By declaring a field `static`, the *same* field is shared among all instances of this class - it is not part of any specific object anymore, which leads to it not being serialized.

To specifically prevent serialization only `transient` is applicable...

Comment: Is there any keyword or annotation which ensures a field can be persisted but not serializable ?

Answer (score 2):

Transient (and in JAXB XmlTransient) signify that the data is ephemeral and not of permanent importance and thus should just be ignored when it comes to matters of persistence.

Static means the value applies that the class level and thus serializing/deserializing it for multiple instances would be unsafe as values would collide.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Let me define serialization once more.

```
A serialization is a process in which we persist state of an object.
```

So, is any static variable is part of an object's state ?..No absolutely not. It is the data which is shared among all objects of a class. So obviously, any static variable is not supposed to be serialized with object's state.

let's assume, we are allowed to persist an object's state. later on, if this variable is changed by some other object/class itself, and if we try to de-serialize the object then what value this static variable will hold. There will be a clash.

So if you want to prevent any **instance variable** from being serialized , do use transient.
when you will de-serialize the object it will be initialized with a default value.